# Why is my recursive function call not returning a value?

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures

I have the following code, trying to return the range between two numbers, and the inner function is not returning a value. It simply returns [Function]. Can anyone tell me why?

```
var range = function(num1, num2) {
    var output = [];  
    return function range2 () {
        if (num2 - num1 === 2) {
            return [num1+1];
        }
        else if (output.length + 1 === num2 - num1) {
            return output;
        }
        else if (output.length + 1 !== num2 - num1) {
            output.push(num1 + 1);
        }
        return range2(num1 + 1, num2);
    };
};
```

//UPDATE: This is my code that ended up working, FWIW:

```
var range = function(num1, num2) {
    var list = [];
    var range2 = function(num1, num2) {
        list.push(num1 + 1);
        if (num2 - num1 === 2) {
            return list;
        }
        else {
            return range2(num1 + 1, num2);
        }
    };
    return range2(num1, num2);
};
```

Comment: `return function ...` returns the function, it doesn't call it.

Comment: you need to execute the function,, so have:   `return function range2(){}();`

Comment: You need parentheses around the definition to call it inline, @Fallenreaper.  `return (function range2(){...})();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `range()` function never calls `range2()`. It simply returns the function expression.

Also, `range2()` needs to take arguments.

```js
var range = function(num1, num2) {
  var output = [];

  function range2(num1, num2) {
    if (num2 - num1 === 2) {
      return [num1 + 1];
    } else if (output.length + 1 === num2 - num1) {
      return output;
    } else if (output.length + 1 !== num2 - num1) {
      output.push(num1 + 1);
    }
    return range2(num1 + 1, num2);
  };
  return range2(num1, num2);
};

alert(range(1, 10));
```

Comment: So this returns an array of a single value, num2-1. Probably has to do with the closure?

Comment: It only does that when `num2 - num1 === 2`. That's the first line of `range2`.

Comment: `range(1, 10)` returns `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: I don't really understand the logic of your algorithm, I ignored that. I just showed how to fix the syntax so that the recursive function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your return will return the definition.  If you are trying to return the execution of the function you will need to add a `()`

See here:

```
var range = function(num1, num2) {
  var output = [];  
  return function range2 () {
    if (num2 - num1 === 2) {
        return [num1+1];
    }
    else if (output.length + 1 === num2 - num1) {
        return output;
    }
    else if (output.length + 1 !== num2 - num1) {
        output.push(num1 + 1);
    }
    return range2(num1 + 1, num2);
  }();  // <----  this will execute the defined function.
};
```

Comment: This returns an array of the correct length, but each value === num1+1. So the arguments aren't getting updated somehow?

Comment: @user5369036 `range2()` doesn't take any arguments. So when you call `range2(num1 + 1, num2)`, those parameters have no effect.

Comment: @Barmar Ahh, gotcha.